# Unset element visibility, change innerHTML, and transisition back

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element on my HTML page that I want to give dynamic content, and I want inserted HTML to transition from 0% to 100% opacity.

## HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

## CSS

```
#content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}

#content.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

## JavaScript

```
function setContent(html) {
  var content = document.getElementById("content");

  //Set hide class
  content.className += " hide";

  //Set HTML
  content.innerHTML = html;

  //Unset hide class
  content.className = content.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g, '');
}
```

Note that `setContent()` sets and then unsets the `hide` class. However, it seems that the browser (Chrome at least) does not invalidate content element until after it return from the function, so the element does not get the chance to transistion. How can I make sure that the animation plays?

**EDIT:** To be clear, `setContent()` is called *after the DOM is loaded*. Imagine an app that clears and repopulates the screen when some action occurs.

Comment: Is it inside `DOM ready`?

Comment: What? `setContent` is a global function.

Comment: This 4 line of javascript run's fast in less than 1ms, what about a setTimeout?

Comment: Yes, `setContent()` is a global function. If you don't see the point, do this: 1) `var foo = document.getElementById("content"); alert(foo);` run this code outside `window.onload`. This will alert `undefined` even if an element exists. Now wrap the same into `window.onload = function(){..Here..}` and you'll see the difference

Comment: Oh, I now see what you mean. But my problem is not that the DOM isn't loaded yet, but that the JS runs so fast that I can't 'reset' the opacity animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using animations?

```
#content {
    padding-left: 32px;
    padding-right: 32px;
    animation: fadein 0.5s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; 
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; 
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear as what the context of this is?

Also where are you calling the function? Is the place where you are calling the function inside a DOM ready function?

In jQuery it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //call the function inside here.
});
```

Comment: That function won't get my animation to work, and also I don't see why I should have to use JQuery for that.